# Hibernate 4.1 using existing jdbc connection

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate inside application already having initialized jdbc connection.
How can i tell hibernate use it?

I saw `SessionFactory#openSession(Connection connection)` in 3.x javadoc but there is not this function in Hibernate 4.1 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
sessionFactory.withOptions().connection(Connection conn).openSession()
```